# assertEquals undefined in debugging mode

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, assert

I'm trying to debug cucmber test in order to figure out reason of failure:

> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<#00[a3b5]> but was:<#00[0000]>

Here is the failing part of the code

```
String actualColor2 = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", hexValue1, hexValue2, hexValue3);
Assert.assertEquals("#00a3b5", String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", hexValue1, hexValue2, hexValue3));
```

In debugging mode I can see all values, and *actualColor2* is **#00a3b5**
But if I run test it fails on this line like *actualColor2* is **#000000**

Tried to rebuild project, restart computer, etc.

[string values looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW5lb.png)

Answer (score 1):

that could be because of the way in which string equals has to be tested. Probably you should try something like

```
Assert.assertTrue('expected matches actual', expected.equals(actual));
```

Not sure if the syntax is exact, but it should work. because I remember reading somewhere that assertEquals may not be 100% accurate when comparing two strings. Please correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: actually small timout solve an issue, element was visible and clickable but somehow there were not enough time to grab a color

Comment: in that case you could use the selnium waitUntil or a similar function. It will wait until the duration we specify or default WebDriver wait time. :)

Comment: I used waitUntil, but even when element become visible & clickable color was "#000000", so I just used simple while solution (while actualColor equals 000000 wait 1sec more)